# How can I change the port of the Event Log on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, event-log

I have following problem.

I have a Linux device connected to a PC over a USB with pipe that is configured as network device and is correctly recognized by Win7 in device manager. This Linux device has fix IP and port which is used for communication with outside world. In my case Windows. The problem is that, on Windows, this port is already assigned to (used by) Event-Log. So the question is:

Q1: Can I change port used by Windows Event-Log to another value and reserve 49153 (0xC001) for my application? If yes, how?

Q2: Is there any possibility to forward network traffic coming from my device to another Windows port? I did some tests, but Windows doesn't even allow me to connect to this port. So application space in Win7 is not an option. Is there a way to do this at kernel level?

I would appreciate any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Reboot. Thats not a reserved port and thus is set on the fly.

```
System service name: Eventlog
Application protocol    Protocol    Ports
RPC/named pipes (NP)    TCP 139
RPC/NP  TCP 445
RPC/NP  UDP 137
RPC/NP  UDP 138
```

Those are the ports hard coded for The event log.